# Karate match contains only deep not working properly

Tags: karate

I am trying to use karate's `match contains only deep` in my project. I am trying to compare two complex json which might or might not contain nested json objects as well as arrays.
I have one json stored in my local and I am also calling api to fetch response which should be same. Although the json objects are same, karate is still showing assertion failed.

Local json:

```
{
 id: "test",
 ...rest of the object
 tags: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
}
```

I am reading this with karate.read("local.json") which i am storing in variable
`expectedResponse`

```
API response
{
 id: "test",
 ...rest of the object
 tags: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
}
```

this api response i am storing in variable `response`

After calling this

`Then match response contains only deep expectedResponse`

I am getting assertion error for tags variable

```
      $.tags[2] | not equal (STRING:STRING)
      'c'
      'd'

      $.tags[1] | not equal (STRING:STRING)
      'b'
      'd'

      $.tags[0] | not equal (STRING:STRING)
      'a'
      'd'
```

Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: there's no way to validate this without a working example. follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue